# How is it possible to have 2 Game Object Prefabs to be Master Client?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

This is really odd considering that the first client that enters the Room is the Master Client and only the first player that enters the room but whenever they spawn in the room both objects are respectively a Master Client and Non Master Client. After spawning in the room and when they load to another level via PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(), Both of them are the Master Client. Because of this, I 2nd player cant interract with what its suppose to do in its own console.

[image]

[image]

I've tried using PhotonNetwork.SetMasterClient but it did nothing to either of the game objects. I need help.

Comment: Is the master client spawning both objects?  I believe what you are looking at is who the owner/creator/controller is, which will be whoever spawned it, unless you pass ownership to another client.

Comment: The spawning of both objects is done by my RoomScript where it spawns objects at the Start Function and then moves them into another scene with PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel() and instantiate them again to bring them back with a Game Manager Script.  Both spawned game objects have Photon View but once they both spawned , they're suddenly both the Master Client.

Comment: If objects are spawned without an owner (belonging to the room) they are always controlled by the master client ... Please show your code!

Comment: here's my code tiny url: 
https://pastebin.com/yp9YuX17 For Game Manager. 
https://pastebin.com/JRbWyd0N For Room Script. 

Let me know if you found something.